# Knockout viewmodel concept

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

I was not able to find an answer for the following... please gimme an advice.
I have a form that is built dinamically basing on metadata being obtained from server via ajax request. It gets about 20 values for display data and also about 10 fields for user input. Thus, the presentation view model and post view model are different. Filled fields are posted back via ajax as well.
How do i apply Knockout view models concept correctly?
1. I make a single viewmodel for displaying and posting data. In this case AJAX call will post back a lot of redundant data to server. Option: i can send a new object that will contain only input fields, but it doesnt look OK in KO concept.
2. I make a single viewmodel containing only fields for user input. Read-only fields to display stay out of KO view model and populated using common jQuery methods (so we're out of pure KO style again)
3. Or?
I appreciate your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout provides the ability to apply MVVM pattern to a client-side (HTML5/Javascript) app.  Your JavaScript view model should provide all the data and properties necessary to operate the view or views that it is responsible for, both for user input fields and display-only fields.

Once you post something back to the server, you're leaving the MVVM world and reaching into another layer to perform some operation.  As a result, I think it's best to formulate JSON that contains only the data that the server needs to complete the request.  On the server side, you may have a C# model with validation attributes or whatever, but, again - you're not trying to adhere to MVVM pattern there.

Hopefully this helps.  I'm happy to elaborate if needed.

Comment: wow, so nice and clean. Thank you! well, how do you create JSON object to post to setrver? Manual mapping?

Comment: I usually create or obtain a JS object that has the data I need and then use JSON.stringify or similar to create the JSON.  Depending on what data you need to send, you may already have it or at least part of it contained in a complex property on your JS view model.