# Best way to pass data back to Server using Knockout.js and Viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

We have an existing ViewModel that has a bunch of properties, but also has lists of enums in order to populate the dropdowns in the view.

I noticed that when you are using Knockout.js and trying to post the Json info back, when you call:

```
ko.toJSON(viewModel);
```

It converts *all* of the model when sending back, including the enums, which are not necessary when trying to send back to the Server to save the data.

I suggested just wrapping the data in a  and doing a post, but is there a nice clean, simple way to post back only the data values without the enums using Knockout?  What is the best way to do this?  Should the ViewModel contain the enums or is that bad design?

Comment: [Read this blog post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html)

Comment: @Posthuma: please post that as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14629775/91189

Yes, your view model should contain all the data, enums, etc the view needs.  The data you post to the server does not need to contain all the view model's data.  A straightforward approach is, when you're ready to send data to the server, construct a model that contains just the data that the request needs.

A slightly different, **more built-in approach** is to expose the model as a property on your view model and bind your view to that where needed.  That way the model is pre-constructed and ready to submit when you are.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to structure your view model like this:

```
var viewModel = {
    enum1: ko.observableArray([...]),
    enum2: ko.observableArray([...]),
    data: {
        ... // other properties you want to post to the server
    }
};
```

And only post back the `data` property:

```
ko.toJSON(viewModel.data);
```

Another possibility, if you use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#omit), is to use the `_.omit` function:

```
ko.toJSON(_.omit(viewModel, "enum1", "enum2"));
```

Comment: Thanks @Cyanfish, I like the data wrapper, fairly clean.